# MailStore software: Archive e-mail profile: authentication failed

Tags: email

Windows 10
MailStore Home Version 23.4.0.22136, build date 2023-11-24

I have an archive profile for my example@hotmail.com webmail account
that has worked for years but recently has been failing when I run it:

An error has occurred.
Authentication failed (EWS). Check user name and password.
If the password is correct, try specifying your UPN Logon
(e.g. user@domain.com) or DOMAIN\username in the user name field.

Here are the 'Archive Exchange Mailbox' property settings:

Access via: HTTPS
Accept all certificates checkbox: unchecked
Host: (Auto Detect)
User Name: example@hotmail.com
Password: is correctly entered
Mailbox: blank (none specified)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?